# Multiple domains and product categories but one company?

Tags: multiple-domains

My company is expanding online, and we are wondering the best way to go about our eCommerce strategy. We sell a wide range of products of a single material, lets use ceramics as an example. The current competition in our niche online is medium level.

We currently have one site selling all our range: ceramicstuff.com

However I have just found that ceramickitchenware.com, ceramicbowls.com, etc are currently unregistered, despite quite decent traffic search volume around those keywords monthly.

What do you guys think about registering these domains to increase traffic? Would I put a standalone sites on those domains, or do I point them to my main domain? Or do I use them a "micro" sites to offer information, and then link to buy at my main domain, etc?

**Summary: I'm looking to employ "spammy" type SEO tricks, multiple domains, etc but the key point is I will be generating REAL content, and offering a REAL QUALITY product. How to proceed?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is, indeed, register the other domain names as well, and use them as aliases. I would then handle the URL and redirect to the specified page in the **main** website.

For example: www.ceramickitchenware.com could be forwarded to *www.ceramickitchenware.com/kitchenware*, which is the same as *www.ceramicstuff.com/kitchenware*.

This way you

- Have to maintain only one website
- The visitor can immediately see the entire range of products
- The visitor will see one type of layout, which helps usability
- The forwarding will work for the Search engine bots as well.
- Your website may score better on a different alias when searching for different keywords, but the website content remains the same

Answer (score 0):

The micro-sites offering information sounds like the best idea but try not to have too many links going into the main domain as it might be seen as creating artificial links. Having an exact match domain name can sometimes rank a site high on keywords that don't have too much competition.

However, with regards to searching for "spammy" SEO techniques, it's probably better to focus your time on some of the huge array of other more productive online marketing avenues because most "tricks" either never worked, currently work but won't in the future or worked in the past but don't now. With so much that could be done you don't want to waist your time on less productive work. It's better to build something that will work long term.

Answer (score 0):

My response is a bit different than what others suggested. I would much rather have several websites owned / operated by me competing against each than others. I mean, there are only top 10 results. 2 is better than 1.

Ofcourse, a lot of factors come into play such as your ability to invest in an infrastructure such as different ip addresses, unique designs, unique content and lastly, SEO (link building etc.)

My strategy has been to create mini-stores instead of mini-sites (information sites). and ofcourse backlinking the mini-stores to my main site looks very legit.